# How to Load Model data joining 2 tables?

Tags: model, sql

Suppose I have a simple *Model A* that target *table A* now I have to add some extra info so I decide to create a *Model B* and save those extra info in a *Table B* with a foreign key pointing to *Table A* index key.

Usually Joins are done in collections but if I load a model the collection is not called, instead only the `resource model` is used.

How can I modify *Model A* to load also data from *Table B* on `load()`?

Comment: Good Question...I like it

Comment: It is a kind of EAV simple implementation ... I found a  kind of solution but I'm waiting for other approach and test it, before posting it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inside resource model class add following function

```
protected function _getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object)
{
    $select = parent::_getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object);

    $select->joinLeft(
        array('t_b' => 'table_b'),
        $this->getMainTable() . '.id = t_b.id',
        array('columnA'));
    return $select;
}
```

When you called `Mage::getModel('modulename/TableA')->load(1)`, this method will join with table_b.

Comment: I think `limit(1)` is not required:`joinLeft()` will be enough ...

Comment: I just set an example for that. You can change this according to your requirement.

Answer (score 6):

I can propose you the approach that I use, and it is quite easy.

**Steps:**

1. Rewrite resource model of Model A (If Model A is yours model and not Magento then you can skip this step)
2. Rewrite method _getLoadSelect() of resource model of Model A. 
   Select query is generated in this method and here you can join your the other tables.

Comment: You beat me to it. +1